# UCanAccess getQueries alters the order of columns in SELECT statment

Tags: ucanaccess

I'm using the below code to load tables from Access queries. It gives the sqlldr error so I printed the query string like shown below and found the order of the columns in the SELECT statement is not the same as in the query in the Access database. I'm very baffled by this. Has someone experienced the same thing?

```
sourceConn = 
    (UcanaccessConnection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://" 
    + path);
List<Query> queries = sourceConn.getDbIO().getQueries();
for(Query query : queries) {
    queryStr = query.toSQLString();
    System.out.println("Query to process: " + queryStr);
}
```

Comment: I've since tried adding columnOrder=DISPLAY which I read about. But it didn't correct the issue.

Comment: You are actually using the bottom level library Jackcess while UCanAccess translates and transforms the select queries into views. I would communicate your baffle to the Jackcess team.

Comment: You can report the Jackcess issue [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/jackcess/bugs/). Be sure to include a [mcve].

Comment: It won't let me open a ticket. The Create Ticket button is greyed out. :-)

Comment: What error are you getting?